# Statistical significance testing when distributions are paired, but samples are not

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mixed-model, independence

I have a situation like the following:

5 distributions A, B, C, D, E of unknown type from which I can take samples to estimate the mean.

I apply an intervention or treatment to all of the distributions.

I take another set of samples from each of these distributions and again estimate the mean.

Effectively, the distributions are paired, but the samples within the distribution aren't necessarily. How can I test for statistical significance of the treatment effect if the samples aren't paired? If they are, is there a different approach beyond combining all of the samples into a single large distribution and performing e.g. a paired t test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to CV!

It's better to think in terms of *dependency* rather than pairing. If you measure experimental units more than once, you can model this dependency using a mixed model with a random effect for the experimental unit.

A simple example using package `lme4` would be:

```
model <- lmer(y ~ treatment + (1 | distribution))
```

Where `distribution` is what you call A to E. Note that this model assumes a normally distributed error term and uses a [random intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/330403/176202).

I'm not quite sure what you mean by A, B, C, D, E being distributions, but regardless, they don't have to be experimental units: They could be locations, time points, different plates, or even different people performing the measurements, each with their own consistent deviation.

In case they *are* locations or time points, it might be that measurements from A correlate strongest to other measurements from A, then to B, then to C, etc. This sort of autocorrelation should be accounted for using an appropriate covariance structure.